# Reasons of more than one ground pin in L293

Tags: microcontroller, integrated-circuit, power-electronics

Why in L390 they provide four pins for the ground and the heat sink? For heat sink,is only one pin is not sufficient? Here is the datasheet

http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/l293d.pdf

Comment: Conducting heat is like conducting electricity - the greater the cross section of the path the quicker heat can be taken through the path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Increasing the number of pins in such IC designs serves at least two purposes:

- Greater conduction path for heat to be drawn away from the IC substrate into the PCB's copper for better thermal dissipation
- Lower impedance for the IC's ground current to run to PCB ground pour, by putting multiple pins in parallel.

A peripheral advantage is greater flexibility in designing a PCB layout.

Answer (score 1):

Multiple pins are used for heat sinking when the extra thermal conductivity is needed.

The datasheet shows the suggested copper layout for extra thermal dissipation:

[image: L293 Heatsink Application]

The chip manufacturer could have chosen a different package; for example, one with a large fin for heatsink mounting, like some amplifiers use:

[image: Amplifier chip with heatsink]

However the amount of heat may not justify such a heat sink when adding a few extra pins will do the job.

Comment: What about the ground pins???Why he select more than one?

Comment: @SHASWAT because the heat energy has to flow through the pins and the (thin) copper of the laminate. By having two pins either side this greatly increases the cross sectional area of the copper available for conduction and improves heat flow. By having all the pins at the same potential (ground) you can form one continuous land of copper maximizing the radiation area for cooling.

Answer (score 0):

Aside from the practical purpose of extra ground pins listed by the others, the reason the l293 specifically needs multiple pins for that is

> The L293 and L293D are quadruple high-current half-H drivers. The L293 is designed to provide bidirectional drive currents of up to 1 A at voltages from 4.5 V to 36 V.

and

> Output Current 1 A Per Channel (600 mA for L293D)
>       Peak Output Current 2 A Per Channel (1.2 A for L293D)

The L293 is a high current chip, allowing up to 4 AMPS total constantly between all 4 channels, and up to 8 Amps if you pulse it. Depending on the current needs, how closely the voltage matches the motors chosen, how it is being driven, etc, there is a lot of heat being generated, and it has to be dissipated somehow. One option is using multiple pins on a standard DIP or SOIC package (since they don't have a heatsink tab option), or using a copper pour, or using an external heatsink. The L293 has the first, and the other two are suggested, and it depends on how you use the IC that determines how much heatsinking you need to do.